# Two ng-clicks on in same div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I've been looking around for an answer for this but I just couldn't find the answer. So what I have is a ng-repeat of items that are in a particular class="list-items". When I click on each of the item in items, it should execute a function. Within each list I have an remove button which I would like to remove the item when clicked.

So some code for reference:

```
 <div ng-click="executeCallback($index)" class="list-items">
        <div class="item-info">
            <span>some info here</span>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="removeItem($index)">X</button>
 </div>
```

So I did right now, in my CSS, i tried using an position absolute on the button and a z-index of like 10000 to show that it is greater than, but when I click the removeItem button, it still calls the executeCallback function. I don't want it to call the executeCallback function.

Is there a way to have the removeItem function be called only when the remove button is clicked and not the parent class?

Comment: This is because when you click on button, this click event bubbles up and fires click handler on parent too.. You need to stop propagation of this event inside `removeItem()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple events in one ng-click.

```
 <div ng-click="executeCallback($index)" class="list-items">
    <div class="item-info">
        <span>some info here</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="removeItem($index);$event.stopPropagation()">X</button>
```

Comment: Thanks really helped!

Comment: I would probably move the `$event.stopPropagation()` into the function, and make the function take in `$event` and pass it into the function from the front end for code re-use purposes, and I don't feel like the html is the place for things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Directives like `ngClick` and `ngFocus` expose a `$event` object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object. [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

You can use this, directly in the HTML template, to stop its propagation by calling `$event.stopPropagation()`. Just add it on the `button` and you should be fine:

```
<button ng-click="removeItem($index);$event.stopPropagation()">X</button>
```